# Reactive way of returning `Map<Long,T>`

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines

I am learning reactive. In an MVC project I have a service method (and the controller has the same signature) like this:

```
@Override
public Map<Long, Question> getQuestions() {
    List<Question> questions = questionRepo.findAllByType(Type.A);
    return questions.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(q -> q.getId(), q -> q));
}
```

Resulting in something similar to this:

```
{
  1: {id: 1, ...}
  2: {id: 2, ...}
  ...
}
```

Now, switching to reactive and kotlin coroutines. What is the proper way to implement this in a reactive way?

This is the signature of the repository:

```
interface QuestionRepository : CoroutineCrudRepository<Question, Long> {
  @Query("select * from Question q where type = :type")
  fun findAllByType(type: Type): Flow<Question>
}
```

**Approaches**

From what I think so far using `Mono<Map<Long,Question>>` seems to make no sense as it would require to block for building the inner map.

`Flow<Map<Long,Question>>` Does not make sense either, because we do not populate multiple maps.

So my best approach for now is not using a `Map`...

```
override fun getQuestions(): Flow<Question> {
  return questionRepo.findAllByType(Type.A)
}
```

...but this would require to change the frontend code (it now needs to convert the list to a map).

I also think of

```
override fun getQuestions(): Flow<Pair<Long?,Question>> {
  return questionRepo.findAllByType(Type.A).map { it.id to it }
}
```

but this would require the frontend to change as well, because the output would look like

```
[{"first":1,"second":{"id":1, ...}]
```

Are there other, better approaches? How would you implement it?

**UPDATE**

added repository.

Comment: A Flow is for something that continually produces new values, but it looks like your repo's `findAllByType` function simply returns a collection all at once. If that's all you want, then a simple suspend function is the way to get the values on a background thread, and you could use `.associateBy(Question::id)` to get your Map. But using a suspend function isn't really reactive programming. For that, your whole structure would be set up to expose Flows that emit values every time there's a relevant change in the repo.

Comment: I added the repository which also returns a `Flow` (using r2dbc with postgres)

Comment: So this function in the repo creates a Flow that emits a new value for each element it finds in its search? If so, this is a behavior I haven't seen before. Usually a Flow returns the latest useful data, but in this case, all of the data has equal, current importance, does it not? Or are you wanting your UI to change in real-time, showing more and more values as they are found by the query? (I didn't even know SQL could do that.)

Comment: I think you are right that the information is not live data. But from my understandings the aim is to have less data in memory, because the spring framework should be the only subscriber to the flow while streaming the result to the client. Using `toList().associateBy(..)` and returning `suspend fun getQuestions(): Map<Long?,Question>` would not allow this?!

Comment: OK, that makes sense to me. The data as it's retrieved is streamed one at a time so it's not all in memory at once. But your UI ultimately needs a Map containing the whole result set at once anyway? If so, then you're only saving the memory space of the List of references to the results. The results themselves ultimately all have to be in memory. To do that, you would make this a suspend function with a mutable map that it fills using its lambda passed to Flow.collect().

Comment: The difference is, that the client (which theoretically is not necessarily a UI) only holds a single user's data while the server handles a lot of users in parallel. If the server does not need to have all results in memory at the same time, but can stream the results from the DB to the client connection that should have less overall memory demand. Regarding the second part of your comment (`Flow.collect()` with a mutable map) I do not understand what the implementation would look like - could you show it?

Comment: Ah, it all makes sense to me now. I've done very little with server/client models so I wasn't thinking in that mindset.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Flow emits elements one at a time that you want to put into a single Map in the client code, then you can collect them into a MutableMap like this and return it.

```
suspend fun getQuestions(): Map<Long, Question> {
    val map = mutableMapOf<Long, Question>()
    questionRepo.findAllByType(Type.A)
        .collect {
            map[it.id] = it
        }
    return map
}
```

If your downstream client code is not expecting a suspend function, I guess you need to wrap this in `runBlocking`, and presumably the downstream code is already handling the fact that this is a long-running function call.

```
override fun getQuestions(): Map<Long, Question> = runBlocking {
    val map = mutableMapOf<Long, Question>()
    questionRepo.findAllByType(Type.A)
        .collect {
            map[it.id] = it
        }
    map
}
```